# How to achieve an effect of AssertJ's satisfiesAnyOf with KoTest?

Tags: kotest

With AssertJ you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745752/3581539) say:

```java
assertThat(list).satisfiesAnyOf(
    listParam -> assertThat(listParam).contains(Tags.SWEETS, Tags.HIGH),
    listParam -> assertThat(listParam).contains(Tags.SOUPS, Tags.RED)
);
```

How am I supposed to express the same with KoTest? Is there some meta-assertion which passes as soon as one of the internal assertions is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [any](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/cc6ae07d3604ef8a95e6038ad3c515833aabf494/kotest-assertions/kotest-assertions-shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/io/kotest/assertions/any.kt#L17), like:

```kotlin
any {
  list.shouldContain(Tags.SWEETS, Tags.HIGH)
  list.shouldContain(Tags.SOUPS, Tags.RED)
}
```

or you could create a composite matcher that tests for either of the tags:

```kotlin
list should contain(Tags.SWEETS, Tags.HIGH).or(contain(Tags.SOUPS, Tags.RED))
```